# Rails: Globally turn off layout for ajax format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In an app with pages that can be loaded normally or from ajax (`jQuery.load()`), how do I setup rails formats properly? Right now I'm using the following code in every action:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render layout: !request.xhr? }
  end
end
```

Is there a way to make this global, and not to have to write it in every action?

**Edit**:

I tried putting it in an `after_filter` as suggested in the comments, but that gave me an error that `Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.`

Comment: you never render anything? why do you use ajax?

Comment: How are your view files called?

Comment: @apneadiving: What do you mean? I just have a `show.html.erb`, of course that gets rendered. I just want it not rendered with the layout when the request is made by ajax.

Comment: ok understood, you send your whole html. Did you try an after_filter with the default responses?

Comment: nice idea, i just tried placing the `respond_to` into an after_filter. however it doesn't work, rails gives an error that `respond_to` was called multiple times.

Comment: i edited the question to make it more clear what i want to do ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do something like this at the top of your controller:

```
layout :set_layout

def set_layout
  request.xhr? ? false : 'your_layout' # layout is false for ajax requests
end
```

Comment: you can shorten this to `layout proc { false if request.xhr? }`

Answer (score 2):

Probably everyone knows it. There's missing "?" character after request.xhr?. Try this.

```
layout :set_layout

def set_layout
  request.xhr? ? false : 'your_layout'
end
```